# Integral of $\arctan(2e^{-x-2})$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need some help with this integral

$$\int\arctan(2e^{-x-2})\,dx$$

I actually stumbled about this function in school and still haven't found a way to solve it properly. I taught myself the basics of integration involving all the common methods like integration by parts or substitution and also know some important substitutions of the latter one. Would appreciate if you guys could give tips for this :) even if they are beyond my horizons

Comment: Pretty sure this integral cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Maple does the answer in terms of dilogarithm.

Comment: Not every function has a closed form integral. Is there a reason to assume this one does?

Comment: Let $f(x)=\arctan\left(\alpha e^{-x}\right)$ (in your case $a=2e^{-2}$.

Let $u=ae^{-x}$. Then $du=-u\,dx$. Then:

$$\int f(x)\,dx = -\int \frac{\arctan(u)}{u}\,du$$
That's probably easier to read, in any event.

Comment: this integral is quite "famous" and has it's own name: a legendre-$\chi$ function of imaginary argument. :)

Comment: Are you really interested in a primitive or just the integral over $\mathbb{R}^+$ or $[2,+\infty)$?

Comment: Im interested in every information you can offer

Answer (score 2):

By setting $x=\log t$, then using integration by parts:
$$\int \arctan(2e^{-x})\,dx = \int \arctan\left(\frac{2}{t}\right)\frac{dt}{t}= \log(t)\arctan\left(\frac{2}{t}\right)+\int\frac{2\log(t)}{4+t^2}\,dt.$$
If now we set $t=2u$, the problem boils down to computing:
$$ \int\frac{\log(u)}{1+u^2}\,du = \frac{d}{d\alpha}\left.\int\frac{u^\alpha}{1+u^2}\,du\right|_{\alpha=0}$$
that is clearly related with the [inverse tangent integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function) and the imaginary part of $\text{Li}_2(iu)$, by partial fraction decomposition.